# Retrieving data from dead pc with Raid 10

Tags: raid, data-recovery, desktop-computer, hard-drive-recovery

I have a Dell XPS 420 that has a great deal of data that I want to retrieve.  I hadn’t used it in a while, and in the midst of powering on, it died.  Now after a bunch of diagnostics, I’ve  concluded that either the power supply or the motherboard or both are damaged.
I don’t want to deal with replacing parts and debugging and all that, unless it’s the only way.

As far as I can recall, I had it configured to run raid 10, and I have 5 sata hard drives that I want to retrieve data from.

Can anyone recommend the best way to go about getting this data?

Comment: Was this software or hardware RAID?

Comment: Also What OS was in use?

Comment: @davidgo - I don’t know if it was software or hardware raid.  I did it through bios I think?   It was Win 7 64

Comment: (I think the XPS420 does not have onboard raid) Did you want to share your service tag so I can look at the config the box shipped with from the Dell website?

Comment: Does [this guide / freeware](http://www.freeraidrecovery.com/library/raid10-recovery.aspx) help? Make sure to backup the HDs to an image or clone drive before starting any recovery.